# Undefined method `on_ride_photo='

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

Model:

```
class Coaster < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug, use: :slugged

  belongs_to :park
  belongs_to :manufacturer

  attr_accessible :name,
                  :height,
                  :speed,
                  :length,
                  :inversions,
                  :material,
                  :lat,
                  :lng,
                  :park_id,
                  :notes,
                  :manufacturer_id,
                  :style,
                  :covering,
                  :ride_style,
                  :model,
                  :layout,
                  :dates_ridden,
                  :times_ridden,
                  :order,
                  :on_ride_photo
```

Test:

```
it { should validate_presence_of(:on_ride_photo) }
it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:on_ride_photo).in_array([true, false]) }
it { should_not allow_value(4).for(:on_ride_photo) }
it { should_not allow_value('lots').for(:on_ride_photo) }
```

Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :coaster do
    association :park
    name 'Nemesis'
    speed 60
    height 60
    length 160
    inversions 4
    on_ride_photo true
  end

end
```

Errors:

> ```
>  Failure/Error: subject { FactoryGirl.build(:coaster) }
>  NoMethodError:
>    undefined method `on_ride_photo=' for #<Coaster:0x007fe9a0aec798>
> ```

Any thoughts. It looks like it's not seeing the setter for on_ride_photo but I have used it in the console and get get and set using it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added this recently? If so you might need to update your test database:

```
rake db:test:load
```